# .htaccess block semalt with wildcard regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below rewrite rule to block semalt.com.  It blocks all traffic referred by them (i.e. 1.semalt.com).  Recently they create a new referrer url (semaltmedia.com). How can I modify the below code to block if they have a word before or after the word semalt with no space or period (i.e. semaltmedia.com)?

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?.*semalt.*\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This returns a forbidden (403) message for a http referer of the following formats :

- http://semalt.com
- https://www.semalt.com
- http://foosemaltbar.com
- http://semalt.com/foo/bar